# How to return address of object array?

Tags: c++

There is a need to return the address of object array from a function.
and catch that address of object array in main. and access each object's data main.

```
#include <iostream>

void* getDetector();

class DETECTOR
{
public:

    int x;
    int y;

    DETECTOR();
    ~DETECTOR();
    void Detect();
};

DETECTOR* getDetector()
{
    // Need to return address of object array.
    return &DetectorObj;  
}

void DETECTOR::Detect()
{
    x = 100;
    y = 200;
}

DETECTOR::DETECTOR(){

    x=0;
    y=0;
}
DETECTOR::~DETECTOR(){}
DETECTOR Detector[3];
int main()
{
    // need catch here address of object array.

    DETECTOR * getDetectorPtr = getDetector(); 

    // need to access value of object array.
    // for e.g. 
    // getDetectorPtr[1]->Detect();
    // std::cout<<getDetectorPtr[1]->x;     
    // std::cout<<getDetectorPtr[1]->y;     

    return 0;
}
```

The above-given code is for returning the address of a single object. But there is a need to return the address of object array from a function.
and catch that address of object array in main. and access each object's data in the main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this?

```
DETECTOR* getDetector();

DETECTOR Detector[3];

DETECTOR* getDetector()
{
    return Detector;  
}
```

Probably the reason your version didn't work is that your definition of the `Detector` array is **after** the definiiton of the `getDectector` function and it needs to be the other way around.

But what is the point of writing a function to return the address of a global array? Why not just use the global itself?

In either case this is wrong

```
getDetectorPtr[1]->Detect();
```

it should be

```
getDetectorPtr[1].Detect();
```

because `getDetectorPtr[1]` a `Detector` not a pointer (strictly it's a reference to a detector).

And as I said above, why not just use the global?

```
Detector[1].Detect();
```

I guess that's your real error, you put `->` when you should have put `.`. In other words you are getting confused about pointers and arrays (very common newbie problem).